# setting content to display on a basic page

Tags: nodes

I'm creating a classified section on my site, and I have a basic page created for the content. How do i set content to go to that specific page?

Thanks for the help

Comment: Are you putting each classified piece in a basic page?

Comment: the basic page will hold all the classified ads.

Answer (score 0):

set up a block view with all your classifieds and then  via admin/structure/blocks find your classified block and configure it to show on your basic page.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is a "View", which requires the [Views module](https://drupal.org/project/views). It'll allow you to easily create pages that list content of any type you create.

Install and enable the Views module, and add a new View. You will see a simple wizard that creates your listing page. Make sure you add the custom path (URL) for your custom page.